# One word document for each unique cell

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word

I have excel tables like below:

column A | Column B | Column C

X         BOB      APPLE

X         BOB      BANANA

X         BOB      PEAR

Y         SARAH    APPLE

Y         SARAH    KIWI

Z         CARL     BANANA

Z         CARL     PINEAPPLE

Z         CARL     WATERMELON

Z         CARL     KIWI

I would like to be able to cycle through column A, for each unique column A value, produce a word document with the value in Column B as the name of the document and Column C as the contents. In the table above, a document titled 'Bob' would contain 'Apple Banana Pear', another document titled 'Sarah' would contain 'Apple Kiwi' , and a third document titled 'Carl' would include 'Banana Pineapple Watermelon Kiwi'.

I've found code, which I've tweaked to my situation, which copies and pastes everything from my Excel into a word document, but this is where I'm stuck. Different excel documents have different numbers of rows, one time it's X, Y, Z in column A, another time, it's V, W, X, Y, Z. I know I'll need to cycle from x = 1 to Len(Cells(x,1)) = 0, but applying this I don't know how. Would appreciate input to my little problem here, and would be interested to learn and understand your reasons.
Thanks as always. Code:

```
Option Explicit


Sub DataToWord()


Dim rng As Range 
Dim wdApp As Object 
Dim wdDoc As Object 
Dim t As Word.Range 
Dim myWordFile As String 
Dim x As Long

'initialize the Word template path
'here, it's set to be in the same directory as our source workbook
myWordFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Document.dotx"

'get the range of the contiguous data from Cell A1
Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
'you can do some pre-formatting with the range here
rng.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter 'center align the data
rng.Copy 'copy the range

Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
'open a new word document from the template
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add(myWordFile)

Set t = wdDoc.Content 'set the range in Word
t.Paste 'paste in the table
With t 'working with the table range
'we can use the range object to do some more formatting
'here, I'm matching the table with using the Excel range's properties
.Tables(1).Columns.SetWidth (rng.Width / rng.Columns.Count), wdAdjustSameWidth
End With

'until now the Word app has been a background process
wdApp.Visible = True
'we could use the Word app object to finish off
'you may also want to things like generate a filename and save the file
wdApp.Activate


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should do what you want:

```
Option Explicit


Sub DataToWord()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim t As Word.Range
    Dim myWordFile As String
    Dim x As Long

    'initialize the Word template path
    'here, it's set to be in the same directory as our source workbook
    myWordFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Document.dotx"

    'Define the exclusive values of column A
    Range(Range("A1"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
    Range("E1").PasteSpecial
    Range(Range("E1"), Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo


    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    'Inserts row necessary for autofilter, since the table has no headers
    Rows(1).Insert

    Dim excValue As Range
    For Each excValue In Range(Range("E2"), Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        'Copies the data for that specific value
        Range(Range("A1"), Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=excValue
        Range(Range("C2"), Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

        'open a new word document from the template
        Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add(myWordFile)

        Set t = wdDoc.Content 'set the range in Word
        t.Paste 'paste in the table
        With t 'working with the table range
        'we can use the range object to do some more formatting
        'here, I'm matching the table with using the Excel range's properties
        .Tables(1).Columns.SetWidth (Range("C1").Width), wdAdjustSameWidth
        End With

        Dim name As String
        name = Range(Range("B2"), Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Value
        wdDoc.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & name & ".docx"

    Next excValue

    'Deletes the inserted row
    Rows(1).Delete
    'Clear the column E
    Columns("E").Clear

    'until now the Word app has been a background process
    wdApp.Visible = True
    'we could use the Word app object to finish off
    'you may also want to things like generate a filename and save the file
    wdApp.Activate


End Sub
```

Just make sure there is nothing in column E, since it places the exclusive values there during execution. Hope it helps.